# How to fix definition of implicit copy assignment operator for 'Mat2D' is deprecated error?

Tags: flutter, dart, rive

i am writing an application that has an animated splash screen, the animation was created using Rive.
the application before adding the rive animation file was working perfectly.
But when i tried to add the rive animation file to the splash screen, it gives me this error:

```
C:\Users\d\Desktop\Flutter Real Projects\weather_app\windows\flutter\ephemeral\.plugin_symlinks\rive_common\windows\..\ios\rive-cpp\include\rive/math/mat2d.hpp(17,5): error : definition of implicit copy assignment operator for 'Mat2D' is deprecated because it has a user-declared copy constructor [-Werror,-Wdeprecated-copy] [C:\Users\d\Desktop\Flutter Real Projects\weather_app\build\windows\plugins\rive_common\rive_common_plugin.vcxproj]
Exception: Build process failed.
```

and here is my code:

```
import 'package:animated_splash_screen/animated_splash_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rive/rive.dart';
import 'package:weather_app/pages/home_page.dart';


class Splash extends StatelessWidget {
  const Splash({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      child: AnimatedSplashScreen(
        splashTransition: SplashTransition.fadeTransition,
        backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
        splash: const RiveAnimation.asset('assets/images/anim.riv'),
        nextScreen: const HomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like this is an issue with the rive plugin - https://github.com/rive-app/rive-flutter/issues/340